How to get the price of an item from App Store based on region using Flutter?
I'm using Flutter and in_app_purchase package to manage my IAP. The problem I've come across is getting different prices for users in different regions. For example something that's 0.99$ in USA, I want to make 50 INR in India.
This is the API I use to display products and their prices from AppStore. My region is currently set to India in the simulator, but the prices are still shown in USD, even though I specifically set separate prices in INR for India in App Store connect.
    final ProductDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryProductDetails(ids);

    for (var product in response.productDetails) {
      print('Product: ${product.title}, Price: ${product.price}');
    }`


I figured out the answer.
The prices you get from the API doesn't depend on the region of the phone, it depends on the App Store's region. So i followed this link to create a sandbox account in India: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/test-in-app-purchases/create-sandbox-apple-ids.
And when using that sandbox account for TestFlight, the correct prices were being shown.
